# How to add my value counts output as a column in my dataset

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How to add my value counts output as a column in my dataset. i want to add the following outputs as a new column in my dataset. how do i proceed to do that. I added a picture of my notebook below

( (report.Total_Inventory == 0) & (report.Total_Sales > 0 )& (report.Analysis == 'unknow')).value_counts()

[Image right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZPQC.png)

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow. The community here is very helpful, but expects users to put some efforts in their attempts and their questions. You should read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as a nice place to start.

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried and what problems are you facing? Also, please paste your code instead of an image as it will help others try it in their environment and, ultimately, it will help them help you